Ошибка 403 при валидации страниц сайта WP
Сайт riggo.ru (WP). Сайт на условно-бесплатном хостинге, поэтому ресурсов немного, но все страницы открываются.
При попытке валидации страниц чекер выдает: IO Error: HTTP resource not retrievable. The HTTP status from the remote server was: 403. Document checking not completed. The result cannot be determined due to a non-document-error.
Проверял разные страницы и в разных браузерах, чистил кэш. Подозреваю, что ошибка где-то в wp, но где именно, не понимаю


Подозреваю, что ошибка где-то в wp, но где именно, не понимаю

Нет никакой ошибки.
Варианта 2: либо твой чекер глючный либо у хостера срабатывает защита (от ботов или по IP или ещё какая-то).

Чекер не мой, а стандартный w3.org/nu. Про ошибку написал, что блокировка может происходить в каком-то плагине, как вариант. Либо из-за малой пропускной способности хостинга. Попробую написать в поддержку хостера, что они скажут

Поддержка хостера исправила блокировку

Встречный вопрос - почему, на "условно-бесплатном хостинге" вам должен предоставляться функционал нормального сайта ? Что б происходила индексаций, ходили боты по ссылкам и и это все...?
Пишите в поддержку хостинга, если она там есть. Можете для теста созать пустую, рабочую index.html страницу что б убедиться, что сам сайт тут не при чем...
